# Understanding call-by-value in Python

Tags: python, call-by-value

Here is my example:

```
def test(word):
    print(id(word))
    word.append('noun')
    word = ['something','new']
    print(id(word))
```

And it works as expected:

```
w = []
test(w)
```

produces:

```
140570192034056
140570192034568
```

and
    w

produces:

```
['noun']
```

But is it possible to assign `w` to new list value inside function? So that after function call `w = ['something','new']`

Comment: What you need is *mutating* the input list, google with that. In your case: `word[:] = ['something','new']` perhaps. See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thank you for reply and helpful link!